# Write a Custom JsonView for cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Hello I want to create a Custom JsonView class, is similar but I want format the data different, any suggestions:

Where to create the class.
How to use instanciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2.x simply extend the current class (if possible):

```
App::uses('JsonView', 'View');
class MyJsonView extends JsonView {}
```

Otherwise you can just create a complete new one, of course.

Either way, drop it into your /APP/Lib folder:

```
/Lib/View/MyJsonView.php
```

Then you can easily use it as

```
$this->View = 'MyJsonView';
```